# How to Replace all occurrence of a character except last in a string in SSIS?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, ssis, data-conversion

I have a string number like this:

```
1.000.000.00
```

So I have to delete all dots except last one, it will look like this:

```
1000000.00
```

Also if there is only one dot it should keep it.

Example:

```
INPUT            |       OUTPUT
-----------------------------------
1.00             |       1.00
1.000.00         |       1000.00
```

What I tried:

I create a derived column with this expression

```
LEFT([Column],FINDSTRING([Column],".",LEN([Column]) - LEN(REPLACE([Column],".",""))) - 1) 
+ SUBSTRING([Column],FINDSTRING([Column],".",LEN([Column]) - LEN(REPLACE([Column],".",""))) + 1,LEN([Column]))
```

It keep the first dot not the last one.

Comment: If its keeping the first dot but not the last, then call reverse on the string before you do anything, then reverse at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use SSIS TOKEN() and TOKENCOUNT() functions.

```
TOKENCOUNT(column,".") == 4 ? TOKEN(1) + TOKEN(2) + TOKEN(3) + "." + TOKEN(4) : 
( TOKENCOUNT(column,".") == 3 ? TOKEN(1) + TOKEN(2) + "." + TOKEN(3) : 
( TOKENCOUNT(column,".") == 2 ? column : 
( TOKENCOUNT(column,".") == 0 ? column: “"  ) ) )
```